# By reversing the polarity of a time domain signal, can I cancel the source audio?

Tags: algorithm, math, audio, fft, noise-reduction

I have an input signal in time domain (that is, discrete 14100 signed integers per second).

If I reverse the polarity (signed-ness) of each value, will I not produce a destructive source-audio canceling signal?

Comment: Well **1\*X + -1\*X = 0**, so Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290539/polarity-vs-phase-shift-in-noise-reduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructive cancellation by simply reversing polarity will occur only if your total software/hardware/system/transducer delay time from your input signal to to your output signal to the point of cancellation is zero (or a very tiny percentage of the period of the highest frequency), and the frequency and phase response of the destructive transducer is absolutely flat.

e.g. only likely in fictional/theoretical models.

Comment: So what do people do in practice?  I mean, I do not need the the formula, but rather the concept.  What are people accomplishing by manipulating the signals in frequency domain for instance?

Comment: Sound moves very slowly in electronic terms.  Based on the placement of your microphones and speakers, you may be able to cancel it by *adding* an appropriate delay to your audio.  [Autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) may allow you to determine this delay automatically -- and it is most easily computed by using the frequency domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Phase inversion (and summing the two) will cancel the signal, resulting in silence. Of course, you must mind numeric limits.